# Как набрать клавиатуре `?

Tags: клавиатура, key

Как можно написать эту скобку на клавиатуре `, постоянно копирую её с другого кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве обычных клавиатур это <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> (то есть, шифт плюс тильда, слева вверху возле <kbd>Esc</kbd>, там обычно ещё буква ё, но только это работает на английской расскладке).